# reduxed-chrome-storage don't work with redux-observable

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, redux-observable, chrome-extension-manifest-v3

I'm bootstrapping a manifest-v3 extension project with react/redux and use a redux interface for [`chrome.storage`](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/extensions/reference/storage/) called [`reduxed-chrome-storage`](https://github.com/hindmost/reduxed-chrome-storage) for state synchronization across extension pages.

I followed [`redux-observable` setup page](https://redux-observable.js.org/docs/basics/SettingUpTheMiddleware.html) to install the middleware as well as the [`redux-devtools/core` setup page](https://github.com/reduxjs/redux-devtools/blob/main/docs/Walkthrough.md#manual-integration) to get a redux log monitor. I'm actually just testing a simple ping/pong state as described in [`redux-observable` example page](https://redux-observable.js.org/docs/basics/Epics.html). Everything was working as expected [at this point](https://github.com/v1s10n-4/miniweb/pull/9/commits/004ae473f0d2f28c93b1edb1fbec685cdfb8c89c).

Then i tried to setup `reduxed-chrome-storage` following the informations on the repo but it seems that it break the middlewares i've just setup. I guess the function `createStore` hooked by `reduxed-chrome-storage` is not called in a way that register them properly. When dispatching an action, it isn't catched by my epic and i get this warning:

> `redux-observable | WARNING: this middleware is already associated with a store. createEpicMiddleware should be called for every store.`

Also the redux-devtools does not show up and trigger this error:

> `Redux DevTools could not render. Did you forget to include DevTools.instrument() in your store enhancer chain before using createStore()?`

Here's the root store logic:

```js
// src/store/store.ts
import reduxedStorageCreatorFactory from "reduxed-chrome-storage";
import { applyMiddleware, compose, createStore } from "redux";
import { REDUXED_STORE_ROOT_KEY } from "../constants";
import { createEpicMiddleware } from "redux-observable";
import RootReducer from "./reducers";
import RootEpic from "./epics";
import DevTools from "../utils/DevTools/ReduxDevTools";

const RCSOptions = {
  createStore,
  storageKey: REDUXED_STORE_ROOT_KEY,
};


export const configureStore = async () => {
  const epicMiddleware = createEpicMiddleware();

  const enhancer = compose(
    applyMiddleware(epicMiddleware),
    DevTools.instrument()
  );
  const asyncStoreCreator = reduxedStorageCreatorFactory(RCSOptions);
  const store = await asyncStoreCreator(
    RootReducer,
    { ping: { isPinging: false } },
    enhancer
  );
  epicMiddleware.run(RootEpic);
  return store;
};
export default configureStore;
```

Here's the repo branch you can clone to reproduce the issue:
https://github.com/v1s10n-4/miniweb/tree/feature/setup-store

*FYI the repo is using yarn 3 with zero-install (PnP)*

just run `yarn start` to open a browser, then open a new tab to show the extension page

**How can i get `reduxed-chrome-storage` working with my middlewares?**